# How do I get the dynamically loaded element that was clicked with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, onclick

I am dynamically loading content into my page. When one of the images is clicked I need to de-select all the others and select the checkbox of the one that has been clicked. I need to do this if either the image, text of checkbox is clicked.

`this` contains all the `li` elements, not just the one that was clicked.
Can anyone suggest how I can identify which of the `li` elements was the one that triggered the code?

```js
$('#colours').click('li', function() {
  $(this).children('li').find('input').prop('checked', false);
  $(this).find('input').prop('checked', true);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="colours">
  <li>
    <label for="">
            <img src="swatch-1.jpg" alt=""><input type="checkbox" value="1"> <span>Red</span>
        </label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <label for="">
            <img src="swatch-2.jpg" alt=""><input type="checkbox" value="2"> <span>Green</span>
        </label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <label for="">
            <img src="swatch-3.jpg" alt=""><input type="checkbox" value="3"> <span>Blue</span>
        </label>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: You could use `$('#colours').on('click', 'li', function() {.... this will reference the clicked li element ....});` if the inner content of ul changes dynamically, see Rory McCrossans post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly it appears that you're attempting to create a delegated event handler, however your syntax for that is not correct and is the cause of your problem. You need to use `on()` with an event name and selector instead of `click`. From there you can select the `li` directly using the `this` reference, something like this:

```js
$('#colours').on('click', 'li', function() {
  $('#colours li').find('input').prop('checked', false);
  $(this).find('input').prop('checked', true);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="colours">
  <li>
    <label>
      <img src="swatch-1.jpg" alt="">
      <input type="checkbox" value="1"> 
      <span>Red</span>
    </label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <label>
      <img src="swatch-2.jpg" alt="">
      <input type="checkbox" value="2"> 
      <span>Green</span>
    </label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <label>
      <img src="swatch-3.jpg" alt="">
      <input type="checkbox" value="3">
      <span>Blue</span>
    </label>
  </li>
</ul>
```

*However*, the behaviour you're creating here, where only one checkbox can be selected at any one time, is identical to the standard behaviour of `radio` input elements. As such, it would make more sense to just use those instead. That way you don't need any JS code at all:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="colours">
  <li>
    <label>
      <img src="swatch-1.jpg" alt="">
      <input type="radio" name="swatch" value="1">
      <span>Red</span>
    </label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <label>
      <img src="swatch-2.jpg" alt="">
      <input type="radio" name="swatch" value="2">
      <span>Green</span>
    </label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <label>
      <img src="swatch-3.jpg" alt="">
      <input type="radio" name="swatch" value="3">
      <span>Blue</span>
    </label>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Yess, I was about to write about `radio`s and saw your answer - Nice one

Comment: Thanks for this! Exactly how I need it.
Ideally I would have liked to implement as a radio button, however, the design is incredibly specific that it should be styled as a checkbox and it seemed easier than re-styling a radio input as a checkbox, and I still need to use some data-attributes to re-render other parts of the page.